# MacOS The application “Logi Options+ Installer” can’t be opened

Tags: macos, logitech

When I try to install Logi options+ on macOS Ventura (13.2) I get the warning "The application "Logi Options+ Installer" can't be opened".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the steps below as a solution to the problem and solved it.

1. download the [options+ software](https://download01.logi.com/web/ftp/pub/techsupport/optionsplus/logioptionsplus_installer.zip).
2. Unarchive and right click on the software and select new terminal at folder.
3. Go to the directory in the package with the command: "`cd Contents/MacOS/`".
4. Run "`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine logioptionsplus_installer`" in the directory.
5. Close the terminal and try the installation again.